# Attempting to create an object to act as an UIAlertController wrapper

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently trying to create a class that will simplify the process of defining an UIAlert.

As the traditional way of initializing an alert is

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title:"hello world", message: "how are you",preferedStyle: .actionSheet)
let ok = UIAlertAction(title:"ok",style:.default,handler: {(action) -> Void in print("ok")})
alert.addAction(ok)
self.presentViewController(alert,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

However, as i am going to be having the same format of alert in alot of places through out my app, I was thinking of making a single class that contains my entire alert object with all actions added so i can simply do:

```
let alert = MyAlert()
self.presentViewController(alert,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

I have

```
class myAlert: UIAlertController{
  init() {
    super.init(title:"hello world", message: "how are you", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
  }
}
```

But I seem to be getting an error "Must call a designated initliazer of the superclass 'UIAlertController'
Can you explain to me what I am doing wrong and send me in the right direction. I am fairly new to swift so any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Subclassing `UIAlertController` is not simple in Swift. It is much easier in Objective C, however, and I would suggest going that road.

Comment: From the docs for `UIAlertController`: *"The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create an `extension` and whenever you want to display a `UIAlertController`, just call the method. With an extension, it can be used throughout your app.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func displayMessageAlert(withAlertTitle alertTitle: String, andMessage message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Usage on a `UIViewController`:

```
    self.displayMessageAlert(withAlertTitle: "Your Title", andMessage: "Display your message here.")
```

Comment: Is there any other way that will allow me to wrap my alert instead of extending the entire UIViewController? It feels like a very excessive to extend all of UIViewController

Comment: If you're displaying one alert, yeah. If you're going to be calling creating multiple alerts throughout an app, I think 6 lines of code is worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Il give this a shot